# IRB console Error when trying to create new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to follow the [reddit on rails tutorial from about.com](http://ruby.about.com/od/redditclone/ss/Reddit-Clone-In-Rails-Part-1-Setting-Up.htm).

I installed Rails with Rails installer and am using git bash to access irb from Windows 7.

I progress to the point in the tutorial where I am creating a new user:

[image]

Here is the error I get after I type in `u = User.new`:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Urnw
```

Comment: Did you try closing the irb and re-opening it?

Comment: I have tried that many times but to no avail. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything several times as well.

Comment: Can you do anything else in the console, like `User.count`? Do all commands produce that error, or just `User.new`?

Comment: I gave up and wrote another tutorial... :(